# Periodic class replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm making a [web-app](https://smmir.netlify.app/), but have a problem replacing my current-weather-icon class in the right moment.
As is, classes are assign without clearing, and it just doesn't work.

I fetch a JSON response and insert the first (correct) class by

```
      weather.iconId = function geticonClass() {
    let prefix = data.weather[0].icon.endsWith("d")
      ? "wi-owm-day-"
      : "wi-owm-night-";
    return `${prefix}${data.weather[0].id}`;
  };
```

with

```
  iconElement.classList.add(weather.iconId());
```

I then have a 15 minute interval for next fetch, after which new class is created and added, but the old one remains.

I tried using

```
function clearIcon() {
var element = element.(document.getElementById("current-weather-icon i")),
element.removeClass();
};
```

And setting an interval for that, but it doesn't work.
[Here's a full JS file.](https://github.com/bonobonobo/Smart-Mirror-Magic-Mirror-Browser-App-With-Charted-Forecast-and-Quote/blob/main/js/app.js)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: `var element = element.(document.getElementById("current-weather-icon i"))` doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you meant `var element = document.getElementById("current-weather-icon i")`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the correction, that's the snippet I was trying to paste, but added another iteration. I thought all the included bits of code were enough. Anyway, I found another solution.

Comment: Great! I'm glad to hear you figured it out. :-) Your best bet is probably to just delete the question, then. There's a "delete" link under the list of tags. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just added a simple function

```
function resetIconClass(){
$('.current-weather-icon i').removeClass()
}
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(resetIconClass, 905000)
});
```

Which basically clears the icon's class right before a new one is inserted.